# Make a panel resize dynamically in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, size, layout-manager

I'm creating an interface composed out of a box layout which contains panels inside every space.

In this specific case I've got a "cascade" of panels, the first is supposed to be a panel with a `FlowLayout` as layout manager, underneath it there's a `GridLayout` and under it there's supposed to be another label.

The thing is that I'd need the first panel to dynamically resize as the window get resized itself.

Here's the problem: I need the first panel to have a specific size in relation to the absolute size.. the thing is that I can't set my preferred size.. in the class I do the following but the panel stays the exact same size as before..

```
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(windowWidth, 50))
```

I'll send the code as soon as I get home, for now the situation is the one written above.

Comment: When the layout starts getting complex, learn GridBagLayout.

Comment: 1) *"I'll send the code as soon as I get home.."*  No, don't post a code dump, or uncompilable snippets.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) `this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(windowWidth, 50))` See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 1):

> I need the first panel to have a specific size in relation to the absolute size

Your main panel should be a BorderLayout (which is the default layout of a JFrame), not a BoxLayout.

Then you add the panel that needs to be a specific size to the BorderLayout.NORTH of the frame.

Then your second panel can use a BoxLayout and add this panel to BorderLayout.CENTER of the frame. Now this panel will get all the extra space as the frame is resize.